# Resizing using Interact JS

Tags: javascript, html, interactive

The following Javascript code is linked to an HTML file. Te file shows Unexpected Identifier error. Can someone please help me out?
I have used interactJS to resize the elements in the class resize-drag.
I have included the HTML, CSS and the Javascript File. I am just trying to implement the resizing example present on the Interact.js website itself.

```
interact('.resize-drag')
  .draggable({
    onmove: window.dragMoveListener,
    modifiers: [
      interact.modifiers.restrict({
        restriction: 'parent',
        elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
      })
    ]
  })
  .resizable({
    // resize from all edges and corners
    edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },

    modifiers: [
      // keep the edges inside the parent
      interact.modifiers.restrictEdges({
        outer: 'parent',
        endOnly: true,
      }),

      // minimum size
      interact.modifiers.restrictSize({
        min: { width: 100, height: 50 },
      }),
    ],

    inertia: true
  })
  .on('resizemove', function (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

    // update the element's style
    target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '\u00D7' + Math.round(event.rect.height);
  });
```

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="drag.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interact-js@2.1.0/interact.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src = "drag.js"></script>

    <title>Drag and drop</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="resize-container">
  <div class="resize-drag">
       </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
.resize-drag {
  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px 20px;
  touch-action: none;

  width: 120px;

  /* This makes things *much* easier */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resize-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted does not contain syntax errors. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi, please be more precise with your problem, can you at less, provide the line where the unexpected identifier exception occurs and your html file.

Comment: Are you linking to jquery in the `<head>` before or after this file?

Comment: I have provided all the three files above now, can you please check and help me out?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the exact error that you are seeing in the console? That should come with the line number where the error occurred. Then you can highlight the corresponding line which is throwing.

Also, welcome! Glad to have you in the community.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering what's the mistake, the javascript code didn't have the `dragMoveListener` function defined (This function is called on the `draggable` method's object parameter)

The fix is just defining and 'activating' the function. Fortunately, the official docs provide the function. Just put this at the beginning of the file:

```
function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target
    // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
        target.style.transform =
            'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
}


window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener
```